# Word for the bottom of the well

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes not the entire well, but only the bottom of it? I've seen some use 'cauldron', but I don't know how common it is. Thanks.

Comment: Not aware of a single word that means "bottom of the well". For a dry well, you could use "floor [of the well]", but I don't think this would work if the well is "working" and contains water.

Answer (score -1):

It’s definitely not *cauldron*. A cauldron is a large pot used to cook or boil food on an open fire.

The phrase *bottom of the well* would imply something along the lines of being in a position of little or no power, or at the lowest rung of a ladder. Is this the sentiment you want to convey, or are you looking for a more technical term?

Comment: I am reviewing posts and this is the third or fourth of your answers that has been flagged for deletion as low quality. This comment is to explain how SE EL&U works. At SE we're looking for answers that provide some explanation and context as explained in the [Help, here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Don't just make an assertion; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Otherwise how can anyone judge if your answer is correct? We only have your word to go on it. As you can see, answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. First day here and I'm earning the ropes. Will add citations.